# Can't connect to NGROK server

Tags: server, virtual-machine, ip-address, ngrok, phishing

After installing blackeye on my VM , I tried downloading and configuring NGROK SERVER but it keeps showing error when I run any command option on blackeye and it won't connect
I tried deleting both the blackeye and NGROK server and downloading it all over and setting it up again but the error still persists